# How do "a headache" & "headaches" make you feel? What is the difference?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, grammatical-number, ambiguity

In the [dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/headache), **headache** is a countable noun.

> head‧ache /ˈhedeɪk/ ●●● S2 W3 noun [countable]
>
> 1 a pain in your head
>
> If you have a headache, you should take some aspirin.

Ok, most people say:

"*I have **A** headache*"

But I seldom hear people say  "*I have headache**s***"

But we do say "*to suffer from headache**s***" ([source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/headache?q=headache))

"**a headache= a pain in your head**" what does it mean?

Let say, my head aches randomly from time to time. Sometimes, in a day, it aches for 1 min and it stops and it returns after 6 hours. But, sometimes in a certain day, it aches nothing.

So, do I say "**I have a headache**" or "**I have headaches**"

or, How do "**a headache**" & "**headaches**" make you feel? What is the difference?

Comment: 'I get headaches' is (all too) common. 'I have headaches' is not as idiomatic (probably because of the incongruous connotation of two headaches at once) but is not unacceptable. / 'I've had two headaches already this week, and now I'm on my third' or 'I've got another headache' are unremarkable. Unlike 'stomach-ache', 'headache' is not commonly used as a non-count noun. 'I have stomach-ache.' /  *'I have headache.'

Comment: "I have a headache" = my head aches now.  "I have/get/suffer from headaches" = I often have a headache (but don't necessarily have one just now).

Comment: People do occasionally say, "I have headaches"; but "I get headaches" is used more commonly, as is "I suffer from headaches." Interestingly, "I have migraines" is used very commonly (so are "I get migraines" and "I suffer from migraines"). (A migraine is a kind of headache.) All of these expressions describe being prone to experiencing headaches, as @KateBunting noted; whereas "I have a headache" describes having a headache at that very moment.

Answer (score 1):

Generally headaches refers to a *series* of headaches. Rather than

> Maybe I should take some medicine, I have headaches right now.

You'll hear

> Maybe I should go to the doctor, I get headaches often.

However it can be used more colloquially as well.

> Calm down! You kids are a bunch of headaches!

Generally though, the plural form of headache refers to multiple instance over time.